# numpy not sorting simple numpy array with duplicate items

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

simple numpy array with repeats won't sort ? need AA AA AA AA AAPL AAPL AAPL etc.

this is the code

```
print('pre sort',my_symbols)
np.sort(my_symbols)
print('post sort',my_symbols)
```

which gives the output

```
pre sort ['AA' 'AAPL' 'AIG' 'AMZN' 'APOL' 'BA' 'BAC' 'BBY' 'BIDU' 'BMY' 'BTU' C' 'CAT' 'YUM' 'AA' 'AAPL' 'AIG' 'AMZN' 'APOL' 'BA' 'BAC' 'BBY' 'BIDU' 'BMY'  'BTU' 'C' 'CAT' 'YUM' 'AA' 'AAPL' 'AIG' 'AMZN' 'APOL' 'BA' 'BAC' 'BBY' 'BIDU' 'BMY' 'BTU' 'C' 'CAT' 'YUM' 'AA' 'AAPL' 'AIG' 'AMZN' 'APOL' 'BA' BAC' 'BBY' 'BIDU' 'BMY' 'BTU' 'C' 'CAT' 'YUM']



post sort ['AA' 'AAPL' 'AIG' 'AMZN' 'APOL' 'BA' 'BAC' 'BBY' 'BIDU' 'BMY' 'BTU' 'C' 'CAT' 'YUM' 'AA' 'AAPL' 'AIG' 'AMZN' 'APOL' 'BA' 'BAC' 'BBY' 'BIDU' 'BMY' 'BTU' 'C' 'CAT' 'YUM' 'AA' 'AAPL' 'AIG' 'AMZN' 'APOL' 'BA' 'BAC' 'BBY' 'BIDU' 'BMY' 'BTU' 'C' 'CAT' 'YUM' 'AA' 'AAPL' 'AIG' 'AMZN' 'APOL' 'BA' 'BAC' 'BBY' 'BIDU' 'BMY' 'BTU' 'C' 'CAT' 'YUM']
```

what am I doing wrong please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `np.sort` function is not in place, it returns an array. To sort in place you must use the `array.sort` method : `my_symbols.sort()`.